# Removing Pernickety 'P's from vocals

Tags: plugin, vocals, audiobook

I've got a very large amount of vocal audiobook material to edit so I was wondering if anyone knew of any plugins that help with 'P's and 'B's that have hit the mic just a little too hard.

I've been using de-esser and de-breath for sibilant and breaths but wondering if there's any new gismo for the Ps and Bs?

Cheers, N

Comment: Its a situation of plosives not sibilance, so I wouldn't expect to have any results with De-essers and the like.  Plosives are just like wind or handling noise.

Comment: Yes I understand that. Tis why I'm looking for something else. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a gizmo to fix this besides: proper use of cedar, izotope or an eq/hipass filter combined with good old pencil in Pro tools.

The point is that the energy from the plosive makes the capsule 'tremble', creating a distortion in lower mid band of the p. So it's not easy to fix..

The only real gizmo to fix this is.... precaution/a good voice artist/good mic placement. 
So i guess you're stuck with manual editing for this book. And remember you're looking for reduction not erasing the p, it is supposed to have some energy.. just not too much.

Also, think about who this is for, a technical listener ar a general audience in an airplane seat at 2000 km. :)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. As much as I thought. Not to worry!

Answer (score 0):

Most of it can be done by just processing the P or B with an EQ.  I just use a 1 band EQ with a preset Hi Pass around 120.  Sometimes you go higher, sometimes lower but that alone works on 95% of them unless it was poorly recorded.

Comment: I have a high band already and that has helped somewhat. Thanks for your input. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Much of the time a bad plosive can be fixed by going in and cutting out the nasty part of the recording. A well-placed HPF also helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a quick and nasty fix then try a dynamic EQ. This can be used to trigger an EQ curve and reduce the bass content on those plosives. It can be inserted on a track and if set up correctly should provide a good solution to otherwise manually going in and removing the offensive sounds via RX or Cedar.